# Session Invalidation on navigating to third party site

Tags: session, invalidation

I have been stuck with this requirement for a while now. I want to restrict the user from accessing his post login session once he navigates from his post login page to third party site like Google or facebook and come back to my site. That is I want to invalidate the session in the above said scenario. Could someone please suggest something?

Comment: Guys!!could someone please suggest something on how to get this implemented?Just a clue atleast please